# new vs override keywords

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding

I've got a question concerning polymorphic methods. I've got two classes: the base class with the non-virtual method `Foo( )` which calls its virtual method `Foo (int i)`  (like this: `Foo() {Foo(1);})` and the derived class which overrides method `Foo(int i)`.

If I call `Foo()` method of an instance of the derived class the walkthrough is as the following: `base Foo() -> override Foo(int i)`. But if I change override method to new the walkthrough is as the following: `base Foo -> base Foo(int i)`. It doesn't even get to the new `Foo(int i)` method. Please, explain the sequence of those methods and why it is the way it is.

```
using System;
class Program
{
    sealed void Main()
    {
        DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
        //Goes to BaseClass Foo() method
        //then goes to Derived Foo(int i ) method
        d.Foo();
    }
}
class BaseClass
{
    public void Foo() { Foo(1); }
    public virtual void Foo(int i) { // do something;
    }
}
class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void Foo(int i)  { //Do something
    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
using System;
    class Program
    {
        sealed void Main()
        {
            DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
            //Goes to BaseClass Foo() method
            //then goes to base Foo(int i) method
            //never gets to Foo(int i)  of the derived class
            d.Foo();
        }
    }
    class BaseClass
    {
        public void Foo() { Foo(1); }
        public virtual void Foo(int i) { // do something;
        }
    }
    class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public new void Foo(int i)  { //Do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

(When using `new`.)

> It doesn't even get to the new Foo(int i) method.

Yes it does - but it executes the `BaseClass` implementation of `Foo(int)` because it's not *overridden* in the derived class. That's the whole point of `new` - it's saying, "I'm not overriding a base class method - I'm a whole new method." If you want to override the base class method, use `override`. The clue is in the keyword :)

So for example, when using `new`:

```
BaseClass x = new DerivedClass();
x.Foo(1); // Calls BaseClass.Foo(int)

DerivedClass y = new DerivedClass();
y.Foo(1); // Calls DerivedClass.Foo(int)
```

But when using `override`:

```
BaseClass x = new DerivedClass();
x.Foo(1); // Calls DerivedClass.Foo(int) // Due to overriding

DerivedClass y = new DerivedClass();
y.Foo(1); // Calls DerivedClass.Foo(int)
```

Comment: Is it something like we go to the base class and call the virtual method, then we check the derived class if it contains override method, and if it doesn't we implement the base virtual method?

Comment: @user3101007: Um, sort of. It's not a matter of "going to" the base method - it's just finding the most derived type implementation of that method, whereas `new` starts a *new* method.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx

Which starts as follows:

> In C#, a method in a derived class can have the same name as a method
>   in the base class. You can specify how the methods interact by using
>   the new and override keywords. The override modifier extends the base
>   class method, and the new modifier hides it. The difference is
>   illustrated in the examples in this topic.

This behavior is by design.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please advise something to read concerning polymorphism   and virtual method table so I can understand it in more details. Because actually I don't quite get the mechanism all the same.

Comment: You might try something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx or http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/c-sharp-abstract-classes